# Correct spelling of Chinese name in English?

Tags: orthography, loanwords

In Buddhism, there is a deity called Skanda. In Chinese, his name is Wei Tuo.
See for example this link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skanda_(Buddhism)

However, my question is, what is the actual correct spelling in English for the Chinese name of this Buddhist deity? Is it Wei Tuo or Weituo?

In the link, you can see that it also says that he is called "Hufa Weituo Zuntian Pusa", in which Wei and Tuo are written together as a single word.

In English, I believe Chinese names using pinyin are written together. For example, Beijing or Tu Youyou, not Bei Jing or Tu You You. This is why I wonder, what's the correct spelling here, Wei Tuo or Weituo? And why? What's the source of the grammatical rule applied to this case?

Comment: There is no rule. Both ways are used for names. For cities, they're usually written together as a single word (except Hong Kong).

Comment: @PeterShor. Whereby "Hong Kong" is not pinyin. Hence the difference.

Comment: There is a difference between "correct" (according to language authorities) and common practice.  In the US "common practice" would generally be determined by usages in the California Zen/beatnik community.

Comment: This is not about grammar or grammaticality. It's about spelling systems. And they differ, so there is no real "correct" spelling.

Comment: @HotLicks Why the *beatnik* community for writing Chinese names?

Comment: @Lawrence - Because they embraced Buddhism.

Comment: @HotLicks I hadn't realised there was a connection there; thanks for the information.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually about English. It's using a different writing system from the usual Chinese characters, but the words and names are still Chinese. Compare this with the Japanese Romaji - the words are still Japanese (not English) even though they use the English alphabet. You might get better guidelines for pinyin conventions by consulting the Chinese publishing community.

Comment: @Hot Licks It's possible that Anglophone language authorities are less well defined than the California Zen/beatnik community.

Comment: Don't know, but make sure you spell the capital of Red China as Peking. That's something anglophones can pronounce. None of this By Jingo nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use pinyin then you ought to do so consistently. If I am not mistaken, the pinyin spelling of this name is Wéituó.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: It might have been downvoted just because someone thinks the question is off-topic. But otherwise, perhaps the lack of references? I haven't decided to upvote yet because I haven't found a reference that clearly supports this. "[Hanyu Pinyin Rules](http://www.pinyin.info/readings/zyg/rules.html#x4.1)" says that polysyllabic Chinese surnames, given names, pen names and nicknames should be written with no spacing between the syllables, but there are also some examples of names that are written with spaces when one part is analyzable as a separate word, such as " Xiǎo Liú" and " Wú Lǎo".

Comment: Since I don't know Chinese or the etymology of this name, I can't tell if "Wei" or "Tuo" can be analyzed as a separate word.